# How to create an OData service for SAPUI5 TreeTable?

Tags: odata, sapui5, treetable

Does someone know if there is a way to create a OData Service that is bindable to an SAPUI5 TreeTable element?

According to the example from here:
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/TreeTable.html

The recursive structure of the data is a list. For example:

```
//Define some sample data 
var oData = {
        root:{
            name: "root",
            description: "root description",
            checked: false,
            0: {
                name: "item1",
                description: "item1 description",
                checked: true,
...
```

I expected to solve that problem with an navigation at the service side. Like

Element with attributes and one attribute points to a list of Elements.

But this would not be the same.

I also detected this thread, but the answer is one year old:
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3389546

All in all, is the answer still true? Or is there a solution, so that the data binding works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use treebinding from ODataModel. First of all, prepare backend. You need to cycle navigation in your entity set. For example, you have entity set `ItemCollection` and you add navigation property `ItemNavigation` which refers to `ItemCollection`. After just bind tree to your TreeTable:

```
var oTreeTable = this.getView().byId("myTreeTable");
oTreeTable.bindRows({
    path : '/ItemCollection',
    properties : {
        navigation : {
            'ItemCollection' : 'ItemNagigation'
        }
    }
});
```

Should work fine but be aware to use it with `Tree` control. TreeTable loads navigation item by click on its parent and Tree loads the whole tree at once.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Do you have a hint where to find the documentation for these navigation topic? I looked into https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/ (Developer Guide) but have not found a topic about that "advanced" part?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no documentation about `ODataTreeBinding`. Information about this topic I've found in test cases and source code.

Comment: hi Nikoley, could you explain more Detail how your oData-model looks like? would be great! and how you retrieved it in UI5 :)

Comment: anyone able to help? full example how to bind ... and how to create the json e.g. from abap (thats my biggest problem.. parent/child structure -> how to?)